# Basic math operations using array concept [java]

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, calculator, operation

I,am creating a java code for doing basic math operations like Addition,Subtraction,Division,Multiplication.I build it using array concept.I want to perform multiple operations within an execution.And must follow the BODMAS rule.My code did run with no error.But did not get the output successfully.
Here is the [minimal reproducible example](https://minimal%20reproducible%20example)  .With Division(/) operator:

```
package trial;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[] val=new float[10];
    char[] op=new char[10];
    float res;
    int lim;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how many operands");
        lim=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<lim;i++) {
            if(i==lim-1) {
                System.out.println("enter a number");
                val[i]=sc.nextFloat();
            }
        else {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        val[i]=sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("enter the operation(+,-,/,*)");
        op[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
        }}
        for(int i=0;i<lim;i++) {
            System.out.print(val[i]+" "+op[i]+" ");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<lim-1;i++) {
            if(op[i]=='/') {
                res=val[i]/val[i+1];
                val=removeArrayF(val,i);
                val[i]=res;
                op=removeArrayC(op,i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("res is"+val[0]);
        }
    static float[] removeArrayF(float[] array,int index){
        float[] r=new float[array.length-1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, r, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(array, index+1, r, index,array.length-index-1);
        return r;
        }
    static char[] removeArrayC(char[] array,int index){
        char[] r=new char[array.length-1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, r, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(array, index+1, r, index,array.length-index-1);
        return r;
        }
}
```

Output example:

```
how many operands
2
enter a number
12
enter the operation(+,-,/,*)
/
enter a number
3
12.0 / 3.0
```

Output stops Here .I didn't get the result of the operation.What is the mistake?What are the changes i need to do for the proper result!?

When I adding an extra `System.out.println("");` statement anywhere on the program, It executes the `System.out.println("res is "+val[0]);` statement.And didnt execute the extra added statement.There I get a problem, the second System.out.println() statement doesn't work. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change one line in the code.

```
res = val[i] / val[i + 1];
```

you are using `+ 2` for index but the operand is in `op[]` and not in `val[]`

Comment: Ohh.. Apologies for that. Basically thats not the problem.I planned it for val[i+1],as you said. I think its my typing mistake. I did edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In `res=val[i]/val[i+2]`, you are dividing the value at `i` by the value at `i+2`. This is not correct because it may result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `i+2` is beyond the length of the array.

Also,result of the division is not properly assigned back into the `val` array after the operation.

You are trying to perform operations and shrink the arrays in one pass. This is not an effective approach. It would be more easy to first apply all division and multiplication operations then proceed with addition and subtraction.

```
package trial;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] val = new float[10];
        char[] op = new char[10];
        int lim;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how many operands");
        lim = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            val[i] = sc.nextFloat();
            if(i != lim - 1) {
                System.out.println("enter the operation(+,-,/,*)");
                op[i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }

        // Perform the operations following BODMAS rules
        for(int i = 0; i < lim-1; i++) {
            if(op[i] == '/') {
                val[i+1] = val[i] / val[i+1];
                op[i] = ' ';
            }
            else if(op[i] == '*') {
                val[i+1] = val[i] * val[i+1];
                op[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < lim-1; i++) {
            if(op[i] == '+') {
                val[i+1] = val[i] + val[i+1];
            }
            else if(op[i] == '-') {
                val[i+1] = val[i] - val[i+1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result is "+val[lim-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then that's not an effective approach.storing the result on val[i+1]  doesn't give accurate result all the time. For example:2+15/5 results 3 in this way. But the actual result is 5.That means a '*' or '/' come as last operator after a '+' or '-' gives inaccurate result

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("how many operands: ");
    int totalOperands = scan.nextInt();
    float[] nums = new float[totalOperands];
    char[] operations = new char[totalOperands - 1];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < totalOperands; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print("enter the operation (+,-,/,*): ");
            operations[j++] = scan.next().charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.print("enter a number: ");
        nums[i] = scan.nextFloat();
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < totalOperands; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            System.out.print(' ');

        System.out.print(nums[i]);

        if (j < operations.length)
            System.out.print(" " + operations[j++]);
    }

    float res = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < totalOperands; ) {
        if (i == 0)
            res = nums[i++];
        else {
            if (operations[j] == '+')
                res += nums[i++];
            else if (operations[j] == '-')
                res -= nums[i++];
            else if (operations[j] == '/')
                res /= nums[i++];
            else if (operations[j] == '*')
                res *= nums[i++];
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("unknown operation");

            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" = " + res);
}
```

Comment: This will not give proper result.This isn't satisfying BODMAS rule.